# Two RHEL 6 machines with static IP cannot ping each other

Tags: rhel6

I am setting up a few servers for a conference at a hotel.
They have setup a separate VLAN for me and gave me 3 static IP's and a DHCP pool of 500.

The issue I have is that the two servers can not ping each other.

Server-1 has 192.168.150.2
Server-2 has 192.168.150.3

From both servers I can ping the gateway (at 192.168.150.1) or any computer using DHCP.
A DHCP using computer can ping both servers.

I have been screwing around with the ifcfg-eth0 file lots and trying various things but can not for the life of me figure it out. I'm more of a systems engineer than an admin and not amazing with the IT side. What can I do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: Just to clarify: From both servers you could ping another machine in the same subnet. And, from another machine in the same subnet, you could ping both servers correct?

Answer (score 1):

Go through the process step-by-step and see where it fails. Does the machine you run `ping` on get an ARP reply? Does it send the ICMP `ping`? Does the other machine receive it? Does it send a reply?

My guess would be that the problem is a software firewall setting in one of the machines.

Comment: No firewall running on either machine at all.

Comment: Yup. I can ping both servers no issues from a DHCP client such as my laptop.

Comment: I got a third static IP 192.168.150.4 and made my Win laptop that static IP and I could ping both the other static IPs... The servers were also both able to ping my Win laptop with the static IP

Comment: Sanity check. You have a pool of 500. What is the netmask they gave you? /23 ? (aka 255.255.254.0) ?

Comment: Yup /23 and 255.255.254.0 is what I'm using on both servers.